# Function glGetString not found during explicit linking

Tags: linux, ubuntu, opengl, mesa, glad

As it seems to be a larger problem to understand my question: It is NOT about any source code or programming implementation, it is about linking an existing and working program! So let me try that again:

I have an application which runs on both, Windows and Linux and makes use of the GLAD-wrapper for OpenGL. (For all the people which never heard about GLAD: is is a wrapper around OpenGL/MESA which ensures proper symbol loading for a defined subset/version of OpenGL). It works smoothly for Windows but recently I found it is not working for Linux any more (Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to be more specific).

The problem is: the call to

```
glGetString = (PFNGLGETSTRINGPROC)load("glGetString");
```

in function gladLoadGLLoader() returns NULL, means the library function glGetString can't be found any more. To clarify this too: not the function glGetString() is returning NULL, when **trying to retrieve a function pointer to glGetString** the NULL is returned as the function could not be found for some reason.

So my question is: what Linux-library would provide the function glGetString()?

Thanks!

Comment: I followed the link. It does exists. It is exactly the same question. It is even by exactly the same author, you. It just is not answered yet, but might be, because it got recently reopened. Your chances for a helpful answer are probably best if you delete this closed quesiton here and improve that other copy as much as possible. Your chances might further improve if you show more patience with people who misunderstood something, maybe even some respect.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I already edited and clarified the question - with absolutely no result, it was not reopened. That's why I created it new. Now that this second question was closed again and now that I have been somewhat unfriendly to the guy who was responsible for this, the first questions was reopened. To sum it up: all this stuff does not work when these "elevated" users don't even understand the question

Comment: It was reopened. I happen to know for sure because a) it currently is open b) it was me reopening it. It was NOT reopened because of you being rude (what an idea), but because you added helpful information and me (together with two others) being forgiving. The user with elevated privileges did not need to understand this question, it was sufficient to recognise that it is exactly the same one. Concerning the three users who initially closed the other copy of this question, they missed a detail which was less obvious before your editing. How about you being forgiving towards them?